# Samsung Front Load washer WF45k6500/AV/A2 trips GFCI Combination AFCI breaker

Tags: electrical, gfci, washer, afci

I have a new home constructed 10/16. The washer was installed at the time of closing.  We did not have an issue until January when the washer required a self clean cycle.  With about 10 minutes left on the spin cycle, it tripped the breaker.  We set it back and it finished.  Since then, around 7 out of 10 spin cycles it trips the breaker, we reset it and go on our way.  Some spin cycles it takes 5-6 times for us to reset the breaker before the washer will actually finish.

We had a tech come out yesterday 2/15/17, and couldn't find anything wrong with the washer.  He called Samsung and they told him we need to switch the breaker from a Square D to a Siemens or a GE breaker.  My fiancé was home, and I wasn't, she passed on that samgsung said it had to do with the digital read out from the washer and it works with the other breaker brands.  After doing some research, it seems that many people have issues with either AFCIs or GFCI breakers.

I can buy a  square D AFCI breaker only.  Any suggestions if that is worth a try?  The other brand breakers GE or Siemens aren't the same shape, they are much shorter, so I'm not sure how well they will mount in the box.  Would the brand really make a difference if it is AFCI/GCFI combo? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Appliance manufacturers are idiots... Well, maybe not all of them, but when it comes to this topic, they're cheap, blame passing, ignoramuses.  Telling you to switch the breaker to a different brand, is probably the dumbest thing I've ever heard.  It would surely be cheaper to by a different brand washer.  Breakers are not interchangeable between brands. For you to change breaker brand, you'd have to have the whole electrical panel replaced.

Comment: The **real** problem here, is that over time the motor in the unit has developed some "*slop*". This  "*slop*" is causing the AFCI to flag the motor as a hazard.  There are ways to prevent this, but appliance manufacturers are too cheap to implement them.  Instead, they tell you to switch breaker brand (idiotic).

Comment: Try calling your local building department, and ask them if it's possible to have a dedicated non AFCI/GFCI circuit installed for the washer.  If they allow the exception, and the washer is the only thing plugged in on the circuit, you can replace the AFCI breaker with a regular breaker.  If they allow the exception, but the washer is not the only thing on the circuit, then you'll have to install a new circuit for the washer only.

Comment: Electronic motor controls are known to have problems with AFCI breakers. I have replaced many GFCI's on garbage disposals and other motor loads. My state has an exception for equipment for loads known to have problems and allows for a dedicated non GFCI/ AFCI protected circuit in this case but a protected outlet needs to be within 3'.

Comment: A simple check.....plug the washer into a non protected outlet on a different circuit to test. If it runs fine, try on another protected circuit. Of it still if fine, then you might have a breaker issue. My local building dept requires a GFCI, but not an AFCI. Might try that. See if you can switch to just a GFCI

Comment: My entire house has the combination breaker gfci/afci.  I don't have another outlet to test.

Comment: Would it be feasible to try a breaker like this that does not have  the arc fault-http://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-20-Amp-Single-Pole-GFCI-Circuit-Breaker-HOM120GFICP/100002959   Or try one like that that is an arc fault but non-gfci-http://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-20-Amp-Single-Pole-CAFCI-Circuit-Breaker-HOM120CAFIC/202353306

Comment: I would probably by a standard breaker non GFCI non AFCI to test the washer only a few $ and then put a GFCI outlet in (a bit cheaper) this way. Most of the newer front loaders have variable speed drives and these do give AFCI breakers trouble. But I live in a state that allows this as an exception to the NEC.

Comment: Before you swap it out, try turning the washer breaker off then holding the test button down while turning it back on, then measuring how long it takes to trip.  An instant trip means it's a fault-to-ground, while tripping at 2 seconds says it's an arc fault, and a trip after 5 seconds says it's either an overload/short, or nothing's wrong.  (This procedure is documented [here](http://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Handout&p_File_Id=363523689&p_File_Name=0700HO1402.pdf&p_Reference=0700HO1402), btw.)

Comment: No follow up? Post ur solution!